# Django CMS plugin nesting --- child doesn't show up in the "structure" interface

Tags: django-cms

I'm trying to create a Django CMS custom plugin that can assemble other plugins.
As far as I can tell, Django CMS can do this using Plugin nesting, and I've followed the examples to create a simple test case.

My expectation is that when you go into the "Structure" tab for a record in the model that has a PlaceholderField that includes the parent plugin, when you add a parent plugin, the pop-up for that model should ALSO have some way to edit/create/add an instance of the child plugin.   But it doesn't --- all I see are the fields for the parent plugin and NOTHING about the children (see screenshot below).

Or am I missing the point of Plugin nesting entirely?

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from cms.models import CMSPlugin
from cms.models.fields import PlaceholderField
from djangocms_text_ckeditor.models import AbstractText

class CustomPlugin(CMSPlugin):
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=200, null=False)
    placeholder_items = PlaceholderField ('custom-content')
    renderer = models.CharField('Renderer', max_length=50, null=True, blank=True,
        help_text='This is just to show that a custom renderer CAN be done here!')

class ChildTextPlugin(AbstractText):
    pass
```

cms_plugins.py:

```
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from .models import CustomPlugin, ChildTextPlugin

class CMSCustomPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = CustomPlugin
    name = _('Custom Plugin')
    render_template = 'custom/custom_plugin.html'
    allow_children = True

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context = super(CMSCustomPlugin, self).render(context, instance, placeholder)
        return context

class CMSChildTextPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = ChildTextPlugin
    name = _('Child Text Plugin')
    render_template = 'custom/child_text_plugin.html'
    parent_classes = ['CMSCustomPlugin',]

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context = super(ChildTextPlugin, self).render(context, instance, placeholder)
        return context

plugin_pool.register_plugin(CMSCustomPlugin)
plugin_pool.register_plugin(CMSChildTextPlugin)
```

[image: Shouldn't there be an interface somewhere that can access ChildTextPlugin ???]

Answer (score 0):

... and the answer is "it was working all the time"  --- the interface comes AFTER the screen I posted above is submitted --- the Custom Plugin entry will have a "+" icon, and it's THERE that the children are found.